# eclipselink joined table inheritance causing errors

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

The background to issue:
data model is Entity Borehole which can have specialized subtypes like GeotechicalBore, WaterBore, GeothermalBore etc.
The implementation I started with was:

```
@Entity(name="BoreHole")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="BH_TYPE_ID",
discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("5")
@Table(name="SC.BORE_HOLE")
public class BoreHole implements Serializable {
etc

subclasses are like:
@Entity(name = "GeothermalBore")
@Table(name = "MINERAL.GEOTHERMAL_BORE")
@DiscriminatorValue("8")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BH_ID",referencedColumnName="BH_ID")
public class GeothermalBore extends BoreHole{

@Entity(name = "PetroleumBore")
@Table(name = "PETROLEUM.PETROLEUM_BORE")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BH_ID",referencedColumnName="BH_ID")
public class PetroleumBore extends BoreHole{
```

The all important access was via this code:

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<BoreHole> q = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM BoreHole x where x.name = '" + name + "'", BoreHole.class);
        List<BoreHole> bhList = q.getResultList();
```

Mostly it worked, but not for all classes. Eg PetroleumBore above worked, but GeothermalBore did not. I got error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-43] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [8] of type [class java.lang.Integer].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(nz.cri.gns.jpaDatabase.entities.BoreHole.BoreHole --> [DatabaseTable(SC.BORE_HOLE)])
```

There definitely was a class for discriminator value 8 and it was in the persistance.xml.

At about this point, things went downhill quickly. To try and make tracking the difference between a subclass that worked and one that didnt, I put the subclasses into same package at the base borehole. It seemed like better practise anyway. When I did this, I got this behaviour:

```
    TypedQuery<BoreHole> q = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM BoreHole x where x.name = '" + name + "'", BoreHole.class);
```

generates SQL like

```
SELECT BH_ID, BH_TYPE_ID, etc FROM SC.BORE_HOLE WHERE((BH_NAME = ?) AND (BH_TYPE_ID =))"))
```

but it always binds the discriminator value of the base borehole class.
(value 5). Ie it is selecting for the particular instance of BoreHole and
not any of the subclasses. I am noob at JPA but this looks like all the
examples I have seen.

Backward step. Next step was what about making BoreHole an abstract class and deriving all boreholes as subclasses?
ie:

```
@Entity(name="BoreHole")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="BH_TYPE_ID", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name="SC.BORE_HOLE")
public abstract class BoreHole implements Serializable {
```

Child entities as before. 
Complete fail. I now get these errors:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-108] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Cannot find value in class indicator mapping in parent descriptor [null].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(nz.cri.gns.jpaDatabase.entities.BoreHole.BoreHole --> [DatabaseTable(SC.BORE_HOLE)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(nz.cri.gns.jpaDatabase.entities.BoreHole.BoreHole --> [DatabaseTable(SC.BORE_HOLE)])
```

I am going backwards not forwards and similar queries on internet seem to have gone unanswered.

Comment: Set logging to finest and look at the logs when the persistence unit is being deployed (EclipseLink lazy loads, so it might occur when the EntityManager is first accessed). This should show it try to load all entities in your persistence unit -check that they are all being found and loaded as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I do have logging set to finest so I will try that right away.

Answer (score 0):

Massive thank you to Chris for the tip. I did look at the log but was looking for errors. Doing as suggested allowed me track the problem to an uppercase typo in persistence.xml I thought it must be simple but was looking for the typos in the wrong place.

After 3 days of no progress, everything is great again.